# How do i fix UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to make a virtual assistant and the only problem left is this one. I don't know how to fix it but here is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)# 0 is male, 1 is female
engine.say('Booting Lora system')
engine.runAndWait()

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_lora():
    command = take_command()
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who' in command:
        question = command
        info = wikipedia.summary(question, 3)
        talk(info)
    elif 'tell' in command and 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
        talk('Sorry I did not understand')

while True:
    run_lora()
```

Comment: If an exception is raised in `take_command()`, then `command` isn't assigned a value and the `return command` will cause an error. Set `command` to something before the `try:` block.

Comment: @Craig he defines the variable in ```run_lora``` he just has to globalize it

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined `command` in `run_lora` it is a private variable
you just need to add `global command`.

```
def take_command():

    global command    # <---- Over Here #############

    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the word `command` to `cmnd` in `take_command()` function. Your command variable is referenced before it was actually declared

```py
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            cmnd = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            cmnd = cmnd.lower()
    except:
        pass
    return cmnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was that I needed pyadio but the pyaudio version is way to old for python 3.8